# Mongo Queries or Pipelines with nested operators

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Why in the MongoDB shell will this work?
`{"created_ts":{ $gt : 200  }}`

But this will fail?
`{"created_ts":{ $gt : {$sum:[100,100]}  }}`

I'm new to mondgo query language and have tried to search/find the correct answers but all the samples make it look it should work....

P.S `created_ts is` a Unix Epoch stored as a NumberLong

Thanks

Comment: Because `$sum` is an aggregation operator.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$sum` operator work with `Aggregation` not with `find`

For details about `$sum` find it here  [$sum (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#sum-aggregation)